# Will DVFS change memory bus frequency too?

Tags: memory

I'm trying to benchmark application performance under different cpu frequency. My target machine is Intel Core 2 Duo CPU . I'm wondering whether DVFS can also change other frequencies , specially memory bus frequency. If not,  the system performance may not change proportionally to the cpu frequency if the program happens to be memory bound.

Some googles give me the term "core to bus ratio" aka cpu multiplier, which is the ratio between internal core frequency over the FSB freqency, if DVFS change the freqency of FSB , then I suppose the memory frequency will also be changed.

Anybody have consider this before? I'm trying to find some Intel architecture introduction, but currently none of them give me this information.